# Русскоязычные книги для изучения RSpec Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Подскажите названия книг или видео курсов по `RSpec Ruby` на русском языке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как в случае с материалами на русском по Ruby вообще, **их практически нет**.
*Во всяком случае, свежих.*

Есть [стайлгайд Better Specs](http://betterspecs.org/ru/) на русском языке, в котором можно получить общее представление о том, какие разделы [официальной документации](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec) открывать. Поскольку **документация по большей части состоит из тестов-примеров** (ориентироваться надо по панели слева), в переводе её на русский язык смысла не так уж много.